# Removing rows from each dataframe in list with condition in R

Tags: r, list

I have such a list:

```
df1 <- data.frame(a=c(NA, NA, 1:10), b=c(NA, 1:11))
df2 <- data.frame(a=1:10, b=c(NA,1:9))
mylist <- list(df1, df2)

> mylist
[[1]]
    a  b
1  NA NA
2  NA  1
3   1  2
4   2  3
5   3  4
6   4  5
7   5  6
8   6  7
9   7  8
10  8  9
11  9 10
12 10 11

[[2]]
    a  b
1   1 NA
2   2  1
3   3  2
4   4  3
5   5  4
6   6  5
7   7  6
8   8  7
9   9  8
10 10  9
```

I'd like to remove all rows with more than 1 NA in a row in each data frame. How can I do that?

I found out how to delete rows

```
lapply(mylist, `[`, -1,)
```

and how to calculate the sum of NAs

```
NAsums <- function(x) {rowSums(is.na(x))}
lapply(mylist, NAsums)
```

But I can't figure out how to combine the two steps..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We loop through the `list` (`lapply`), use `rowSums` to get the number of NA elements in each row, convert to a logical vector (`<2`), and use that to subset the rows.

```
lapply(mylist, function(x) x[rowSums(is.na(x))<2,])
#[[1]]
#    a  b
#2  NA  1
#3   1  2
#4   2  3
#5   3  4
#6   4  5
#7   5  6
#8   6  7
#9   7  8
#10  8  9
#11  9 10
#12 10 11

#[[2]]
#    a  b
#1   1 NA
#2   2  1
#3   3  2
#4   4  3
#5   5  4
#6   6  5
#7   7  6
#8   8  7
#9   9  8
#10 10  9
```

Comment: Great, thanks. I played around with this for so long but must have had messed up the brackets or so..